# Another storyboard was created for localization of a storyboard in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, localization

I am using base internationalization, and I am adding Simplified Chinese localization of my storyboards and strings. Before, when I click on the checkbox for Chinese here

[image]

A new strings file for Simplified Chinese will be created for the storyboard. But now, when I click it, this pops up.

[image]

I don't get it. Why is it creating another storyboard in zh-hans.lproj directory, rather than a strings file. I have Localizable Strings selected above.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to add two storyboard in your project for localization.
see,https://www.youtube.com/edit?o=U&video_id=xZ7_HkMkQhU

Comment: Hi, I don't think you understood my problem. I clearly stated that Xcode created another storyboard when I checked the Chinese option for localization which is shown in picture 1. So, I did not created that storyboard, but Xcode generated it.